# logscale histogram of a matrix

Tags: gnuplot, octave, histogram

I have data organized like this:

```
XPos   Data1 Data2 Data3
100    2     3     4
1000   20    30    40
10000  200   300   400
```

And I would like to draw a bar chart where the first column is used as X, and each data row is used as a cluster.

Problem is: I need to use logscales on Y and X columns should be placed with equal size and space between them.

Something like this: [image: Desired output]

Is it possible in gnuplot? When I use logscale, I get this message:

> > Log scale on X is incompatible with histogram plots

Or, it is possible using octave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what you need.
However, using the following script:

```
set ytics auto
set logscale y
set style data histogram
set style fill solid border -1
plot 'data.dat' u 2:xtic(1) t col, '' u 3 t col, '' u 4 t col
```

gives me the following plot:
[image]

I guess `set logscale y` is the key.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I did 3 errors: logscale was set also on x, the data had a comment on the first row which I forgot and I did not know 'xtic()'! Thanks :)